# Convert a char array into an integer (big and little endian)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, endianness

I am trying to convert a char array into integer, then I have to increment that integer (both in little and big endian).

Example:

```
char ary[6 ] = { 01,02,03,04,05,06};
long int b=0; // 64 bits
```

this char will be stored in memory

```
              address  0  1  2  3  4  5
              value   01 02 03 04 05 06   (big endian)
Edit :        value   01 02 03 04 05 06   (little endian)
```

-

```
memcpy(&b, ary, 6); // will do copy in bigendian L->R
```

This how it can be stored in memory:

```
       01 02 03 04 05 06 00 00 // big endian increment will at MSByte
       01 02 03 04 05 06 00 00 // little endian increment at LSByte
```

So if we increment the 64 bit integer, the expected value is 01 02 03 04 05 07. But endianness is a big problem here, since if we directly increment the value of the integer, it will results some wrong numbers. For big endian we need to shift the value in b, then do an increment on it.

For little endian we CAN'T increment directly. ( Edit : reverse and inc )

Can we copy the w r t to endianess? So we don't need to worry about shift operations and all.

Any other solution for incrementing char array values after copying it into integer?

Is there any API in the Linux kernel to it copy w.r.t to endianess ?

Comment: I hope you don't really meant `about s**t operations and all.`. :P

Comment: Do you need to read integer from char array, increment it, and store back, or what?

Comment: i need to read hex values from char array, and increment it then store increment value some where.

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason why you are using octal numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read up on documentation. [This page](http://www.bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/ByteOrder.html) lists the following:

```
__u64 le64_to_cpup(const __le64 *);
__le64 cpu_to_le64p(const __u64 *);
__u64 be64_to_cpup(const __be64 *);
__be64 cpu_to_be64p(const __u64 *);
```

I believe they are sufficient to do what you want to do. Convert the number to CPU format, increment it, then convert back.

Comment: I found these API use full,

Comment: used conveted into cpu formate( be to cpu ), and incremented. Thanks #unwind

Answer (score 5):

Unless you want the byte array to represent a larger integer, which doesn't seem to be the case here, endianess does not matter. **Endianess only applies to integer values of 16 bits or larger.** If the character array is an array of 8 bit integers, endianess does not apply. So all your assumptions are incorrect, the char array will always be stored as

```
  address  0  1  2  3  4  5
  value   01 02 03 04 05 06
```

No matter endianess.

However, if you memcpy the array into a `uint64_t`, endianess does apply. For a big endian machine, simply memcpy() and you'll get everything in the expected format. For little endian, you'll have to copy the array in reverse, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
  uint8_t array[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
  uint64_t x=0;

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(uint64_t); i++)
  {
    const uint8_t bit_shifts = ( sizeof(uint64_t)-1-i ) * 8;
    x |= (uint64_t)array[i] << bit_shifts;
  }

  printf("%.16llX", x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you saved me,I was totally confused about endianess after reading the question

Comment: your are correct, thanks man for clarification. The problem i wish to tell you guys was about memcpy, it wont be in correct format if we do memcpy in little endian, so as you said we do need to reverse it. But i am looking for other api that can take care of these endian issue.